# Reason of a directory size being zero

Tags: linux

Was doing some copy operation on a linux machine to the director /misc. and it did not perform well. After digging came to know that size of /misc is 0.
**Logs:**

```
[root@gd911-linux-host1 misc]# ls -lrt
total 0
[root@gd911-linux-host1 misc]#
```

But created a directory myself which empty only & checked its size, showing 4 bytes.
**Logs:**

```
[root@gd911-linux-host1 random]# du -sk
4       .
[root@gd911-linux-host1 random]#
```

Please let me know what is the reason of this.

Comment: It probably is showing 4kilobytes not 4 bytes

Answer (score 3):

Both commands are functioning 100% correctly. When you create a directory, for example:

```
mkdir -p misc
```

The directory is empty. If you use `ls` to list the files in the directory, it reports as expected:

```
$ ls -lrt misc
total 0
```

Because there are `0` files in the directory. Now when you look at `du` the disk usage taken by the directory itself, it correctly notes the size of the file (inode, links, etc.) that represents the directory on disk. Example:

```
$ du -sk misc
4       misc
```

Rest assured both are working correctly on your system. `ls` reporting the number of files contained within the directory, and `du` reporting the actual size that the directory itself takes on disk.

Answer (score 1):

Stricto sensu, **a [directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_%28computing%29) cannot be *completely* empty** (on Linux and POSIX systems). It is *required* to have the two entries for `.` (the directory itself) and `..` (the parent directory). Use `ls -als` to list all entries in some directory. See [ls(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html) & [stat(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stat.1.html). If using `*` be aware of [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) by the shell (the shell's globbing for `*` is skipping file names starting with `.`, see [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html))

In particular [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) & [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) will give at least these two `.` & `..` entries (except on failure).

Hence, a directory is *always* taking some place for those two mandatory entries and for additional metadata (i.e. [inode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode)).

Your `/misc` might have not been filled by previous `cp` commands perhaps for lack of permissions. Be sure that its owner is appropriate (the one used by `cp` commands). Check with `stat /misc` or with `ls -ald /misc`. Then `chmod u+rwx /misc` at least (see [chmod(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chmod.1.html); you could use as *root* the [chown(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chown.1.html) command to change ownership).