# Linux what is the benefit of having . and .. as hard link and not soft links?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm learning linux and is syntax at bash,
when I learned about hard and soft link I so that you can't crate a hard link for directory , because it will makes loops.

But . and .. are hard links, why is that ?

I mean, why . and .. can be hard link while I can't create an hark link on other directory, why they aren't just soft link?

Why . and .. breaking the role of no hard link to a directory?

Can someone explain the benefit of having them as hard link and not soft links?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How . and .. can be hard links, isn't it breaking the file system ?

The POSIX specification requires that, and Unix tradition had `.` and `..` be hard links since several decades (if they did not exist, the file system could be corrupted or disappear or become broken without possibility of repair).

Read the wikipage on [hard links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) to understand them.

Remember that (on Unix and Linux) files don't have necessarily names. On Unix and Linux, a file is an [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) (see also [inode(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inode.7.html)) and can have one (this is the usual case), zero or several names. A directory is a mapping between names and inodes and is conceptually required to have both `.` and `..` entries. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29485691/841108) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22746667/841108) answers to related questions.

Read also [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) notably the chapters about [files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_file), [directories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)), [file systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system). Read also about [VFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_file_system).

Hard links are usually not allowed on directories (and [link(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html) would then fail) to facilitate a [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) scheme in the kernel and forbid [circular references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference) in file trees.

The `.` and `..` entries are created at [mkdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mkdir.2.html) time. The `..` entry could be changed by [rename(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rename.2.html) (and *conceptually* by [mount(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html)). The [rmdir(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/rmdir.2.html) syscall requires the directory to be empty, i.e. to contain *only* those two  `.` & `..` entries. See also [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html) (and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/101536/50557)).

Comment: I mean, why . and .. can be hard link while I can't create an hark link on other directory, why they aren't just soft link? why . and .. breaking the role of no hard link to a directory?

Comment: Because the POSIX specifications require them to be hard links. As to *why* is it so, read any good book on Unix or Linux internals

Comment: OK, thank, I will read more about it